# Расширение и сужение в Java

Tags: java

Наткнулся на 2 статьи, в которых сужение и расширение определяются по разному (противоположно друг другу). Как я полагаю:

A peremen = new B() - сужение т.к. мы сузили функционал класса B набором методов класса A?

((B)peremen).method2() - расширение т.к. мы расширили premen и теперь доступны методы не только класса A, но и B?

```
public class Test1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A peremen = new B(); // сужение

        ((B)peremen).method2(); // расширение


    }
   static class A{
        public void method1(){
            System.out.println("method A");

        }

    }

     static class B extends A{

         @Override
         public void method1() {
             System.out.println("method B");
         }
         public void method2() {
             System.out.println("2 method B");
         }
     }


}
```

Comment: Вопрос в чем???

Comment: @AntonShchyrov правильно я понял, что является расширением/сужением или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно. Проще проверить на реальном примере:

```
List<> list = new LinkedList<>()    //будут доступны только методы List.
((LinkedList) list).getLast();      //успешно выполнится
```